# http://localhost:3000/applink/_next/webpack-hmr?page=/ keeps 308 redirecting to https://localhost:3000/applink/_next/weback-hmr?page=%2F

Tags: next.js, localhost, hot-reload, webpack-hmr

I'm running multiple NextJS dev servers and all servers can be accessed through main server (home) which has port 3000. When I access a Next server (app1) which runs in port 3001 through localhost:3000/app1 (using rewrites and assetPrefix); the hot reload fails as shown here
[Network Inspect webpack-hmr redirect failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jV00.png).

Strangely enough, opening localhost:3000/ (home) the hot reload works on its own server. Same as localhost:3001/app1.

I have tried chrome://net-internals/#hsts to delete localhost from domain security policies, clear chrome browser cache, remove Strict-Transport-Security in security headers. I'm not quite sure of what the root cause can be and I've been looking over the places. Nothing works. Any insight is more than appreciated.